# Undeclared identifier for nested types from ancestor

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I don't understand why the descendant class `TChild` can't see the ancestor nested type `TLNested` and the compiler still reports an error that it cannot find it.

> E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TLNested'

The original simplified hierarchy looks like this.

```
  TAncestor = class abstract
  public
    type
      TLNested = class
      end;
  strict protected
    procedure DoSometing(AParam: TLNested); virtual; abstract;
  end;

  TChild = class(TAncestor)
  strict protected
    procedure DoSometing(AParam: TLNested); override;
  end;
```

Unfortunately, even if I simplify it even more, it still doesn't work. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

```
  TAncestor = class
  public
    type
      TLNested = class
      end;
  end;

  TChild = class(TAncestor)
  public
    procedure DoSometing(AParam: TLNested);
  end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use fully qualified name.

```
  TChild = class(TAncestor)
  public
    procedure DoSometing(AParam: TAncestor.TLNested);
  end;
```